# Wp8 Background Agent Image

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents

I have been working on a application. This app running in the background and I wanna to see some image about this app. Like this

[image]

How can I search or how can I do that I don't know.

I hope I can explain. Thanks all replies.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an API to manipulate the notification bar on windows phone. I found this article: http://blog.duc.as/2011/10/08/using-the-system-tray-to-show-progress-in-windows-phone-7-mango/ which might help you along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in Windows Phone. You can change only tile or write on lock screen.

Comment: Omg! It's really bad.

Comment: Use tile. It's better, bigger and overall nicer idea that bunch of icons in the status bar (like in Android).

Comment: I know it's very usefull. But firstly a lot of user use before Android device after that they want to see like that in windows phone :/